# Is it necessary to have a Paypal Merchant Account in order to develop an App using Paypal Api?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, paypal

I want to develop an Android Application with in-App purchasing using Paypal Api. According to the requirements of the Application the users (Buyers and Sellers) should have the paypal account and I am the owner of the app and I don't require it. 
I mean the transaction will be directly between the Buyers and Sellers so my question is 
'Is it necessary to have a paypal merchant account in order to use their API? 
If yes! I live in Pakistan and paypal doesn't offer its services here. 
What should I do ? Is there anyother way ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need used PayPal.initWithAppID API using the merchant's unique application ID (appID) that PayPal has provided.

Answer (score 0):

As a transaction broker, the easiest implementation would be to ask the sellers to provide something like a "Buy Now" button.

Since this will be an Android app and it involves monetary transactions, I recommend to to read the [Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement](http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html) and the [Android Market Developer Program Policies](http://www.android.com/us/developer-content-policy.html), in particular the sections related to payments.